# Is there an idiomatic Javascript way of avoiding providing a default value for a failing `Array.find()`?

Tags: javascript, arrays, idioms

I've got working code for creating an object on the fly:

```js
// dummy sources
const departments = [
 { code: 'DA', title: 'Department A' },
  { code: 'DB', title: 'Department B' },
  { code: 'DC', title: 'Department C' },
  { code: 'DD', title: 'Department D' },
]
    
const reviewers = ['Department A','Pub Lunches','Department C','Department D']
    
const validationObject = {}
    
// actual code
reviewers.forEach( (reviewer, index) => {
 const dept = departments.find( dept => dept.title === reviewer) || { code: reviewer.replace(/[ ]/g, '_').replace(/[/W]/g, '') }
 validationObject[dept.code.toLowerCase()+'_reviewer'] = {blah:'blah'}
})
         
console.log(validationObject)
```

It works, but the creating a dummy object just to defeat the error when grabbing the `code` element of an undefined result (when there's no matching element in departments) looks awkward.

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: I think your code looks fine. You could prepare some functions for this functionality (the dummy code and the `dept.code.toLowerCase()+'_reviewer'`, which would make it a bit fancier. But the general idea is OK.

Comment: something that's not clear to me in your question - your code provides an alternative value for a reviewer that isn't in the departments, that will result in something like `Pub_Lunches`, but your question is that you are creating the dummy object just to defeat the error. Do you want to keep that Pub_Lunches item or ignore it? If the latter then the bit where you add something to the  validationObject should be wrapped in `if (dept && dept.code) { /*etc*/ }`

Comment: If I don't add the `{ code: 'Pub_Lunches' }` object generation, then the `dept.code` calc in the next line fails. I *want* to create a property for all incoming elements, but shorten the name for items I know about already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ES6 should be something like this

```
const dept = {
    code: reviewer.replace(/[ ]/g, '_').replace(/[/W]/g, ''),
    ...departments.find( dept => dept.title === reviewer) 
}
```

Comment: D'oh! Yep that does look better - and avoids a coverage issue with the 'Istanbul' tool

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use an external library `get()` from lodash will prevent you from creating unnecesary objects and at the same time will help you a lot with properties validation:

```js
const { get } = require('lodash')

const backupCode = reviewer.replace(/[ ]/g, '_').replace(/[/W]/g, '').toLowerCase() + '_reviewer';
const key = get(departments.find( dept => dept.title === reviewer), 'code', backupCode)

validationObject[key] = {}
```

otherwise you could use the spread operator.